# SQL Server communication disconnection after transaction completes

Tags: sql-server, database

I'm working on an automatic retry mechanism for our DAL. I'm trying to understand if the following scenario is possible when working with a SQL Server database:

1. I connect and start a transaction
2. I make some changes to the DB
3. the  transaction is committed
4. the connection is lost and no return value reaches me (the client)

In other words - is returning the value of a command is part of a DB transaction and it won't commit successfully if the connection is lost?

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Comment: I assume you are doing this in code from a 'remote' application

Comment: Related https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/47404/does-disconnecting-the-network-stop-a-query - it doesn't exactly answer your question though. I presume the acknowledgement to the client will be after the transaction is confirmed committed to the transaction log (as acknowledging as committed  to the client and then losing the transaction would be worse). So even if it were to check the connection is alive immediately prior to committing I guess there is a possibility the connection is lost concurrently and the client is never notified.

Comment: @PeterSmith - correct